# Best Aphorisms in Computer Science

Tags: computer-science

There are many that I'd like to quote, but I think the best, in my opinion, is the one by **Edsger Dijkstra** :

*"Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence"*

And you? What are the best quotes about Computer Science?

Comment: Isn't that statement false if P=NP?

Comment: This belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it's a poll, not a question, and doesn't belong on any SE site.

Comment: We already have [Great programming quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among many...

> There are two ways of constructing a
> software design;
>
> One way is to make
> it so simple that there are obviously
> no deficiencies.
>
> And the other way is
> to make it so complicated  that there
> are no obvious deficiencies.
>
> The first
> method is far more difficult.

[C A R Hoare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._A._R._Hoare)

Answer (score 8):

> Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen.

-- Edward V. Berard

Answer (score 3):

"Programming is a race between software engineers striving to build better and bigger idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning."

Answer (score 2):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

IIRC it was from Knuth

Answer (score 2):

Another Knuth quote: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Answer (score 2):

> The three chief virtues of a
>   programmer are: Laziness, Impatience
>   and Hubris.

-Larry Wall

Answer (score 2):

Via a work colleague:

> Java - write once, debug everywhere